# Oracle dump import

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, import

After a system failure I bought a new server and now I'm trying to recreate the Oracle database I had.

I have a dump file which was made with the command `exp` and `full=y`. Can I restore the full database from this dump? If yes, how?

Oracle 11g on Windows server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you used the old import utility (with 11g you should use the DataPump), then:

```
imp "/ as sysdba" file=<dumpfile> log=<logfile> full=y
```

If I remember well, old export utility in 11g doesn't save empty table, due the "deferred segment creation". Make a check after the import.

Answer (score 0):

This bat script must be located in the same folder as the dump file which should be on a folder off your main drive for convenience sake.

```
imp userWithDBAPrivileges/password LOG =C:\dump\logs\import.log file =yourDumpFile01.dmp fromuser=user1 touser=user1
```

As Goliardico points out you have to have the same tablespaces and users but the users cannot have any objects with the same name as objects to be imported.  The caution about empty tables is also applicable and a real gotcha if you don't notice.